# Если нету слова, то не выводить

Tags: php

Как выводить только эл-ты, у которых встречается слово `IMDB`

Вот код

```
$slovo = nl2br($desc3, true);
$arr = explode('<br />', $slovo);
foreach($arr as $imdb) {
    if(false !== strpos($imdb, 'IMDB')) {
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Совсем запутался))) можете написать весь правильный код?

Comment: добавил простой пример

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = ['qwe','asd','zxc','qwe','asd','zxc'];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (strpos($item,'qwe') !== false) { // если qwe встречается - выводим item
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: и `break;` еще бы добавить

Comment: @Theartofbeingalive зачем? Насколько я понял, нужно не первое вхождение а все выводить

Comment: вы правы, не заметил.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так,
добавил

```
else $imdb = '';
```

получилось

вот весь код

```
    $slovo = nl2br($desc3, true);
    $arr = explode('<br />', $slovo);
    foreach($arr as $imdb) {
        if(false !== strpos($imdb, 'IMDB')) {
                break;
        }
        else $imdb = '';
    }
```